# Formatting of list - text alignment between different bullets

Tags: html, list, formatting

as of now I did all my reports in LaTex and only recently I started to use HTML (for many reasons). What I am looking for is the HTML solution for a text formatting. The problem is the following: in a list of N bullets each bullets should be formatted in this way:

bullet#1 [text-of-length1] <- space -> [text-of-length2]

bullet#2 [text-of-length3] <- space -> [text-of-length4]

the 4 lengths could be different, but I want the text [length2] and [4] (the 2nd text part in each bullet), to start at the same point in space.

In LaTex this is solved imposing a certain size of a box that contains the first part of the text, thus pushing the second part of the bullet to start only after this box. 
I tried to write each text in a table cell and partially works, but now the text is not aligned to the bullet (as if the cell is aligned but the text is slightly off-set up, the vspace = "bottom" did not help).

```
<ul style="list-style-type:square">

<li><table style="display:inline"><tr><td width="100">test</td><td>test</td>
</tr></table></li>

<li><table style="display:inline"><tr><td width="100">test2</td>
<td>test2</td></tr></table></li>

</ul>
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the style `vertical-align: baseline;` to table cells. This will align the table cell contents with bullet.

```
td {
    padding: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
    td {
        padding: 1;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
</style>

<ul style="list-style-type:square">
    <li>
        <table style="display:inline">
            <tr>
                <td width="100">test test test test<br/>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>

    <li>
        <table style="display:inline">
            <tr>
                <td width="100">test2</td>
                <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. 
If you know other(s), more logical than what I suggested, workaround, please let me know. But this definitely does what I want.

Thanks again